# Random forests Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, random-forest

I have been trying to train a random forests algorithm to sort of predict fire occurrences, using MODIS fire occurrence data as an outcome variable and elevation, distance from urban areas, air temperature, wind v and u components, LAI and NDWI as predictor variables. But I cannot get Google Earth Engine to explain the trees and check if they were created properly. Even when I tried to export it to my drive its run for over 7 hours without any success. Might anyone know why?

Just a quick heads up, I am completely new to Javascript and GEE and am barely learning the ropes so it would also really help if any suggestions could have some sort of short example so I can visualize what u mean.

Edit: corrected even more portions of the code so here it is

```
// Mato Grosso Region
var point = ee.Geometry.Point(-55.689, -12.78);
var adminUnits = ee.FeatureCollection('FAO/GAUL/2015/level1');
var featuresIntersectingPoint = adminUnits.filterBounds(point);
var MatoGrosso = ee.FeatureCollection(featuresIntersectingPoint);

// Date filter
var startYear = 2019;
var endYear = 2019;
var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(startYear, 8, 1);
var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(endYear, 11, 30);
var dateFilter = ee.Filter.and(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate));

// Fire Occurrence dataset
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS')
  .filter(dateFilter)
  .filterBounds(MatoGrosso);

var clipToStudyArea = function(image) {
  return image.clip(MatoGrosso);
};

var clippedDataset = dataset.map(clipToStudyArea);

var maskFire = function(image) {
  var fires = image.select('T21');
  var threshold = 300; 
  var fireMask = fires.gt(threshold);
  var firePolygons = fireMask.reduceToVectors({
    geometry: MatoGrosso,
    scale: 200,
    maxPixels: 1e8,
    geometryType: 'polygon'
  });

  firePolygons = firePolygons.map(function(feature) {
    return feature.set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'));
  });

  return firePolygons;
};

var firePolygonCollections = clippedDataset.map(maskFire).flatten();
var firePolygonsWithinBounds = firePolygonCollections.filterBounds(MatoGrosso);

// Split the polygons into 70% training and 30% testing
var split = 0.7;  // 70% of the data

var withRandom = firePolygonsWithinBounds.randomColumn('random');  // Adds a random column between 0 and 1
var trainingPolygons = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split));
var testingPolygons = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split));


//Wind and Temp
var era5 = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5/DAILY')
  .filterDate('2019-08-01', '2019-11-01');

var clipToStudyArea = function(image) {
  return image.clip(MatoGrosso);
};
  
  var clippedWindnTemp = era5.map(clipToStudyArea);

// Daily mean 10m u-component of wind
var era5_u_wind_10m = clippedWindnTemp
  .select('u_component_of_wind_10m');

// Daily mean 10m v-component of wind
var era5_v_wind_10m = clippedWindnTemp
  .select('v_component_of_wind_10m');

// Daily mean 2m air temperature
var era5_2mt = clippedWindnTemp
  .select('mean_2m_air_temperature');

// Visualization palette for u- and v-components of wind
var visWind = {
  min: 0,
  max: 30,
  palette: [
    'ffffff', 'ffff71', 'deff00', '9eff00', '77b038', '007e55', '005f51',
    '004b51', '013a7b', '023aad'
  ]
};

// Visualization palette for temperature
var visTemperature = {
  min: 250,
  max: 320,
  palette: [
    '000080', '0000d9', '4000ff', '8000ff', '0080ff', '00ffff', '00ff80',
    '80ff00', 'daff00', 'ffff00', 'fff500', 'ffda00', 'ffb000', 'ffa400',
    'ff4f00', 'ff2500', 'ff0a00', 'ff00ff'
  ]
};
// Define a function for IDW spatial interpolation using a 3x3 kernel
function idwInterpolation3x3(image, power) {
  // Define a 3x3 kernel where each value is the Euclidean distance from the center
  // Use a small value (e.g., 0.0001) for the center to prevent division by zero
  var distances = [
    [Math.sqrt(2), 1, Math.sqrt(2)],
    [1, 0.0001, 1],
    [Math.sqrt(2), 1, Math.sqrt(2)]
  ];
  
  // Compute the IDW weights directly from the distances
  var weights = distances.map(function(row) {
    return row.map(function(distance) {
      return Math.pow(distance, -power);
    });
  });
  
  var weightKernel = ee.Kernel.fixed(3, 3, weights);
  
  // Convolve the image with the weight kernel to obtain the interpolated values
  var interpolatedImage = image.convolve(weightKernel);
  
  return interpolatedImage;
}

// Define the power parameter for IDW
var power = 2;

// Perform IDW spatial interpolation for each dataset using the 3x3 kernel
var interpolatedUComponent = idwInterpolation3x3(era5_u_wind_10m.mean(), power);
var interpolatedVComponent = idwInterpolation3x3(era5_v_wind_10m.mean(), power);
var interpolatedTemperature = idwInterpolation3x3(era5_2mt.mean(), power);

// Visualize the interpolated data


// Filter the ERA5 dataset for the desired date range
var startDate = '2019-08-01';
var endDate = '2019-11-30';

// Filter the u-component of wind
var uComponentCollection = era5_u_wind_10m.filterDate(startDate, endDate);

// Filter the v-component of wind
var vComponentCollection = era5_v_wind_10m.filterDate(startDate, endDate);

// Filter the 2m air temperature
var temperatureCollection = era5_2mt.filterDate(startDate, endDate);

// Reduce the collections to extract the values at the specified point
var uComponentValue = uComponentCollection.mean().reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
  geometry: MatoGrosso,
  scale: 200,
maxPixels: 1e8
});

var vComponentValue = vComponentCollection.mean().reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
  geometry: MatoGrosso,
  scale: 200,
  maxPixels: 1e8
});

var temperatureValue = temperatureCollection.mean().reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
  geometry: MatoGrosso,
  scale: 200,
  maxPixels: 1e7
});


//LAI
//LAI Initialization
var modisLAI = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MCD15A3H');
var defaultVisualization = modisLAI.first().select('Lai');
var defaultVisualizationVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 100.0,
  palette: ['e1e4b4', '999d60', '2ec409', '0a4b06'],
};
Map.setCenter(-60.55, -2.84, 6);

// Function to mask clouds and cloud shadows based on the QC band
var maskCloudsAndShadows = function(image) {
  var qcBand = image.select('FparExtra_QC');
  var cloudMask = qcBand.rightShift(5).mod(2).eq(0);
  var cloudShadowMask = qcBand.rightShift(6).mod(2).eq(0);
  var combinedMask = cloudMask.and(cloudShadowMask);
  return image.updateMask(combinedMask);
};


// Apply the mask to the LAI ImageCollection
var maskedLAI = modisLAI.map(maskCloudsAndShadows);
// Function to clip images to the study area
var clipToStudyArea = function(image) {
  return image.clip(MatoGrosso);
};

var LAIResult = maskedLAI
  .filter(dateFilter)
  .filterBounds(MatoGrosso);

var ProjectLAI = LAIResult.map(clipToStudyArea);

// Display the mean LAI for the specified date range and region
var LAIImageSingle = ProjectLAI.select('Lai').mean();
Map.addLayer(LAIImageSingle, defaultVisualizationVis, 'MaskedLAI');

//NDWI
var NDWI = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_32DAY_NDWI')
  .filterDate('2019-08-01', '2019-11-01')
  .filterBounds(MatoGrosso); // Filter the dataset based on the Amazon polygon
//clip to amazon
var clipToStudyArea = function(image) {
    return image.clip(MatoGrosso);
};
  var clippedNDWI = NDWI.map(clipToStudyArea);
var NDWIcolorized = clippedNDWI.select('NDWI');
var colorizedVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1.0,
  palette: ['0000ff', '00ffff', 'ffff00', 'ff0000', 'ffffff'],
};

// Convert the ImageCollection to a single Image by computing the mean 
var NDWIcolorizedSingle = NDWIcolorized.mean();

// Visualization parameters for NDWI
var colorizedVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1.0,
  palette: ['0000ff', '00ffff', 'ffff00', 'ff0000', 'ffffff'],
};

// Add the single NDWI image to the map

//Band name is 'NDWI'

// Year Range
var startYear = 2019;
var endYear = 2019;

// Date objectsbe
var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(startYear, 8, 1);
var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(endYear, 11, 30);

// Date filter for August to November in each year
var dateFilter = ee.Filter.and(
  ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate)
);
// Apply the date filter
var filteredDataset = clippedNDWI.filter(dateFilter);

Map.setCenter(6.746, 46.529, 6);
Map.centerObject(MatoGrosso, 6);


//elevation
// Import the dataset and select the elevation band
var elevationDataset = ee.Image('CGIAR/SRTM90_V4');
var elevation = elevationDataset.select('elevation'); 

// Clip the elevation data to the selected Mato Grosso feature
var clippedElevation = elevation.clip(MatoGrosso);

// Set elevation visualization properties
var elevationVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 2000,
};

// Set elevation <= 0 as transparent and add to the map;
Map.setCenter(-55.689, -12.78, 8); 


// distance from urban areas and farmland
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MCD12Q1');

// Filter the dataset for the year 2019
var landCover = dataset
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')
  .select('LC_Type1');

// Define the values to keep (cropland, urban-built-up areas, and LC_Type1 = 14)
var valuesToKeep = [12, 13, 14];

// Mask to keep the specified values
var mask = landCover.map(function(image) {
  var isKept = image
    .eq(valuesToKeep[0])
    .or(image.eq(valuesToKeep[1]))
    .or(image.eq(valuesToKeep[2]));
  return isKept.updateMask(isKept);
});

// Convert mask from ImageCollection to single Image
var maskSingle = mask.first();

// Create a distance function
var createDistanceBand = function(image) {
  var distance = image.fastDistanceTransform(1000).sqrt().reproject({crs: 'EPSG:4326', scale: 200});
  return distance.rename('Distance');
};

// Compute distance directly from maskSingle
var distanceSingle = createDistanceBand(maskSingle);

// Clip the distance image to the Mato Grosso bounds
var clippedDistanceSingle = distanceSingle.clip(MatoGrosso);

// Visualization parameters for the clipped distance band
var clippedDistanceVisParams = {
  min: 0,
  max: 200,  // Adjust this range as needed
  palette: ['blue', 'red']
};


// Center the map on the Mato Grosso region
Map.setCenter(-55.689, -12.78, 6);

//training bands
var bands = ['u_component_of_wind_10m', 'v_component_of_wind_10m', 'Lai', 'mean_2m_air_temperature', 'NDWI', 'elevation', 'Distance'];

//selecting predictor bands
var uWindBand = interpolatedUComponent.select(['u_component_of_wind_10m']);
var vWindBand = interpolatedVComponent.select(['v_component_of_wind_10m']);
var tempBand = interpolatedTemperature.select(['mean_2m_air_temperature']);
var NDWIband = NDWIcolorizedSingle.select(['NDWI']);
var LAIband = LAIImageSingle.select(['Lai']);
var elevationBand = clippedElevation.select(['elevation']);
var distanceBand = clippedDistanceSingle.select(['Distance']);

// Include the predictor bands in the predictor image stack
var predictorImage = ee.Image.cat([uWindBand, vWindBand, tempBand, NDWIband, LAIband, elevationBand, distanceBand]);

// Define the names of all predictor bands
var bands = ['u_component_of_wind_10m', 'v_component_of_wind_10m', 'mean_2m_air_temperature', 'NDWI', 'Lai', 'elevation', 'Distance'];

// Extract predictor variables using the created trainingPolygons
var trainingSamples = predictorImage.sampleRegions({
    collection: trainingPolygons,
    properties: ['label'],
    scale: 200
});

// Create a classifier
var randomForestClassifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest({
  numberOfTrees: 100,
  seed: 0
}).setOutputMode('CLASSIFICATION');

// Train the Random Forest classifier with the trainingSamples
var trainedClassifier = randomForestClassifier.train({
    features: trainingSamples,
    classProperty: 'label', 
    inputProperties: bands
});


// Model interpretation
// Extract explanation of the classifier
var explanation = trainedClassifier.explain();
// Convert the explanation to a Feature for exporting
var explanationFeature = ee.Feature(null, explanation);

// Export the explanation to Google Drive as CSV
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ee.FeatureCollection([explanationFeature]),
  description: 'RF_Explanation',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});

// Accuracy test
// Extract predictor variables from the testingPoints (your 30% withheld data)
var accuracySamples = predictorImage.sampleRegions({
    collection: trainingPolygons, // Use the previously defined testing points
    properties: ['label'],
    scale: 200
});

// Classify the accuracy dataset
var predictions = accuracySamples.classify(trainedClassifier);

// Compare the predictions to actual labels
var errorMatrix = predictions.errorMatrix('label', 'classification');

// Print the error matrix and the overall accuracy
// Export the error matrix to Google Drive
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ee.FeatureCollection([
    ee.Feature(null, {matrix: errorMatrix.array().toList()})
  ]),
  description: 'errorMatrix',
  folder: 'GEE', // Optional: specify a folder name if desired
  fileNamePrefix: 'errorMatrix',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});

print (explanation);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3a1bb190cf5b8998d78793ae9dcd85f3?noload=1

Answer (score 2):

Your script has several major problems.

1. You seem to be treating the FIRMS results as "points" when in fact, they're polygons.  When you sample those, you're getting a TON of points all right next to each other so you've got massive spatial auto-correlation problems, but in addition, you're then attempting to sample/train with all of the points in those polygons (3 million; the `size` of `fireOccurrenceTrainingPoints`), which is too many.
2. You're rasterizing FIRMS, only to turn it back into an image, which you then rasterize again, before sampling those locations back into a feature collection. You seem to be doing that in order to select a subset of the FIRMS regions for training vs. accuracy. That's a ton of unnecessary computation.

You've also got a lot of other bad practices in your script, like:

- reusing variable names (`dataset` gets used for several datasets), and redefining the same function multiple times (`clipToStudyAreaonly` is defined 4 times;  the last definition gets used).
- using image.projection() improperly (the fireOccurrenceTrainingImage has no projection, but that's what you're using when you vectorize it),
- unnecessarily clipping everything with a complex polygon (7000 pts).  The sample, sampleRegions and stratifiedSample and reduceRegion(s) functions all take a region; you don't need to clip anything.
- You're doing an IDW interpolation on the mean wind and temperature images, however you're doing it at 30m/pixel when those images are 0.25 degrees/pixel (about 27km/pixel).
- You're taking the mean of a bunch of 32-day composites, without dealing with clouds; just merging the clouds into the results. (you shouldn't use those composites for anything other than visualization purposes; make your own, dealing with clouds properly).

All that said, I think you can skip about 80% of this script if you simply put together the images you want (perhaps fixing the problems mentioned) and run a stratifiedSample instead of doing any vectorization.  You can simply take the max() and gt() over the FIRMS data to get a fire/no-fire mask, and use it as the strata.  Then you can control how many points you want of each, and you split those sampled points into training and validation.

Comment: MB, Its really my first time working with javascript and GEE to any capacity. Pretty big leap for me coming from Qgis to this but nobody told me i'd need this much coding knowledge for the university unit i took, and for most of the ones used in class he just kinda did some processes on already pre-curated image collections.

I think ive cleaned up my code since you posted this but i dont think i've really fixed what actually matters in terms of computation. Could you specify what u mean by not needing to clip it by the 7k pt polygon? How do I specify that I only want what is in that state?

Comment: Also, from what I understand, image collections generally have a band that tells u what their %cloud cover is, if it is not accounted for already, and I dont think there were such bands in the collections I chose. Is there another way i Identify and mask out cloud cover?

As for the mean wind and temperature changes, I suppose a simple reprojection wouldn't do, is there any way other than finding a different dataset in which I can account for this?

Comment: MB, I found that LAI and the land cover collection has a quality band, though i have not found such bands for the others